# Return index after calculating distance metric

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, similarity

Given a DF with 4 features and 1 index column :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, size= (100,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['index'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)
```

I want to calculate the Manhattan distance given input from a user. The user's inputs will be represented by a,b,c,d. The function is defined below.

```
def Manhattan_d(a,b,c,d):

    return (a - df['A']) + (b -df['B']) + (c - df['C']) + (d - df['D'])
```

When the answer is returned to me, it comes out as a list. Now, I want to find the minimum value returned to me AND link it back to the index number from where its from.

If I do return(min(formula)), I get an output of one number and I can't locate it back to the index it was originally from. If it's easier, the index represents a category. So I need to find the category with the minimum output after the formula is applied.

Hope that's clear.

Comment: Since your function Manhattan_d returns a series, you can use Manhattan_d(a,b,c,d).idxmin() to get the index with minimum value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a better approach is to apply Manhattan distance to each row of the dataframe. At that point, you can use `.idxmin()` to find the index of the point in the original dataframe which is most similar (has lowest Manhattan distance) to the point a,b,c,d that you fed the function.

```
def Manhattan_d(a,b,c,d, df):
    return df.apply(lambda row:abs(row['A']-a)+abs(row['B']-b)+abs(row['C']-c)+abs(row['D']-d), axis=1).idxmin()
```

Note: Manhattan distance requires the absolute value of the difference, which I have included.

Another note: it is generally good practice to pass all variables into a function, which is why I included `df` as an input to your function.

Another possibility is to use existing implementations, such as the [DistanceMetric](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.DistanceMetric.html) class from Scikit-learn.

Comment: Thanks Jake! I'm new to the data science field and have no idea what best practices are. I appreciate the feedback!